# A clean way to add a button on top of table - Bootgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I am using Jquery-Bootgrid. http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

I need a situation where user can select a Row, then the user clicks a button for Edit/Delete.

I want this to be re-useable. So I have created a Method:

```
function dataTable() {

    var self = this;

    self.tableListUrl = "";
    self.gridObject = null;

    self.InitilizeAjaxTable = function (tableDiv, tableListUrl) {

        parameters = parameters || "";
        self.tableListUrl = tableListUrl;

        self.gridObject = $("#" + tableDiv).bootgrid({
            formatters: {
                "actions": function (column, row) {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            rowCount: [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
            requestHandler: function (request) {

                var model = fleetMaintenance.filterModel.GetModel();
                model.Current = request.current;
                model.RowCount = request.rowCount;
                model.Search = request.searchPhrase;
                return JSON.stringify(model);
            },
            ajaxSettings: {
                method: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            ajax: true,
            url: self.tableListUrl,
        }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e) {
            alert('Loaded');
        });
    }).on("click.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, columns, row) {

});
},

self.RefreshTable = function () {
    self.gridObject.bootgrid("reload");
},

}
```

Then I can initialize my table using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var dt = new dataTable();

        dt.InitilizeAjaxTable("sitesList", '@Url.Action("SitesList","Sites")');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table id="sitesList" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="iSiteId" data-visible="false" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric" data-sortable="false">Site Id</th>
            <th data-column-id="sSiteName" data-order="desc">Site Name</th>
            <th data-column-id="sNotes">Notes</th>
            <th data-column-id="sAddress">Address</th>
            <th data-column-id="sCity">City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I know I can set the `rowSelect` and the `selection` to `true`.

I can bind the click event on the button, what I need to know is **How can I append a button at the start of this table with data attributes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I extended the `jquery-bootgrid` Object and created a `customDataTable` Object.

All you have to do is copy/paste the following code in a JS file and link it to your website after linking jquery bootgrid JS file.

> **NOTE:** I have added a custom `requestHandler` and `responseHandler` but you can edit this or remove it if you don't need it - as this is
>   what I am using in my application.

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.customDataTable = function(options) {
    var namespace = ".rs.jquery.bootgrid";
    var settings = $.extend({
      tableListUrl: null,
      buttons: [],
      refreshTables: [],
      updateParameters: '',
      canSearch: true,
      rowCount: [10, 25, 50, -1],
      ajax: true,
      css: {
        actions: 'actions btn-group',
        dropDownMenu: 'dropdown btn-group'
      },
      searchSettings: {
        characters: 2
      },
      rowSelect: true,
      templates: {
        header: "<div id=\"{{ctx.id}}\" class=\"{{css.header}}\"><div class=\"row\"><div class='col-md-12 bootgridMessage'></div><div class=\"col-sm-12 actionBar\"><p class=\"{{css.search}}\"></p><p class=\"{{css.actions}}\"></p></div></div></div>"
      }

    }, options);

    if (!settings.canSearch) {
      settings.templates.header = "<div id=\"{{ctx.id}}\" class=\"{{css.header}}\"><div class=\"row\"><div class='col-md-12 bootgridMessage'></div><div class=\"col-sm-12 actionBar\"><p class=\"{{css.actions}}\"></p></div></div></div>";
    }



    var createButtons = function() {
      var buttons = settings.buttons;
      var htmlButtons = [];

      $.each(buttons, function(name, props) {
        var css = "";
        if (!props.enabled) {
          css = " hidden";
        }
        var tempBtn = $("<button/>", {
          text: props.Text, //set text 1 to 10
          id: "btn_" + props.Text,
          "class": props.css + " pull-left" + css,
          click: props.click
        }).attr({
          "style": "margin-right: 5px;"
        });

        htmlButtons.push(tempBtn);

      });
      return htmlButtons;
    };
    var buttons = createButtons();
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dt = $(this).bootgrid({
      css: settings.css,
      rowCount: settings.rowCount,
      selection: settings.rowSelect,
      rowSelect: settings.rowSelect,
      searchSettings: settings.searchSettings,
      converters: {
        datetime: {
          from: function(value) {
            return moment(value);
          },
          to: function(value) {
            var customDateTime = moment.utc(value);
            return customDateTime.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
          }
        },
        date: {
          from: function(value) {
            return moment.utc(value);
          },
          to: function(value) {
            var customDateTime = moment.utc(value);
            return customDateTime.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
          }
        }
      },
      requestHandler: function(request) {
        var model = {};

        model.Current = request.current;
        model.RowCount = request.rowCount;
        model.Search = request.searchPhrase;

        for (var key in request.sort) {
          model.SortBy = key;
          model.SortDirection = request.sort[key];
        }

        return JSON.stringify(model);
      },
      responseHandler: function(response) {
        return response;
      },
      ajaxSettings: {
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
      },
      ajax: settings.ajax,
      url: settings.tableListUrl,
      templates: settings.templates
    }).on("selected" + namespace, function(e, row) {

    }).on("load" + namespace, function(e) {});

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      parentDiv.find(".actionBar").prepend(buttons[i]);
    }
    return dt;
  };

}(jQuery));
```

And then I created the bootgrid tables like this:

```
var assetsList = $("#grid-data").customDataTable({
  ajax: false, // set to true to load data using Ajax
  buttons: {
    dlt: {
      Text: "Delete",
      css: "btn btn-danger",
      enabled: true, // false to hide button
      click: function() {
        alert('Delete clicked')
        var selectedId = assetsList.bootgrid("getSelectedRows")[0];
        if (selectedId == undefined) {
          alert('No Item Selected');
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    update: {
      Text: "Update",
      css: "btn btn-primary",
      enabled: true,
      click: function() {
        alert('update clicked')

      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can pass as many buttons as you need, and can also define the functionality they perform.

For Ajax Tables, just pass in the correct URL and set ajax to true:

```
var assetsList = $("#grid-data").customDataTable({
  tableListUrl: '/Controller/Action',
  ajax: true,
```

You can see a working example of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/m5j722gz/

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me:

```
$("#grid-header").find('.actions.btn-group').append('<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Edit <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've implemented my button to fit nicely with the `bootgrid`:

```
$("#grid-header").find('.actionBar').prepend('
    <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button">
        <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        Add
    </button>
');
```

It works nicely and it's pretty easy to customize your button in there.

Comment: My table header has id 'grid-data-header'.  So I used $("#grid-data-header") instead of $("#grid-header") and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery prepend function after the table is loaded:

```
$('#sitesList tr').prepend(
     '<th>' +
         '<button type="button" testDate="' + yourData + '">' +
              'click me' +
          '</button>' +
     '</th>'
);
```

To add a button to the top of the table.

Comment: This ruins the styling of the bootgrid table

Comment: Try this here: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples looks fine to me? $('#grid-basic tr').prepend(
     '<th>' +
         '<button type="button">' +
              'click me' +
          '</button>' +
     '</th>'
);

Comment: I will give this a shot